# HP DL380 G6: Where is Temperature Sensor 30 (I/O Board Zone)?

Tags: monitoring, hp, hp-proliant, physical-environment

In ILO2 firmware 2.15 on my DL380 G6, the Temp 30 sensor (location: I/O Board Zone) indicates 65C and my fans are running at 78% capacity. The Caution level for this zone is 110C, and the Critical level is 115C.

Would anyone know where is located the Temp 30 sensor? There are 8 other sensors that point to "I/O Board Zone" locations.

Thank you,

Alexandre

Answer (score 13):

The sensor is likely in the PCIe cage area, above the P410i RAID controller on the motherboard. This would be the rear-right corner of the server chassis looking from the front of the server.

"I/O Zone" in this context means the PCIe bus. Can you give us any detail about any PCIe cards installed in this server? Depending on what's installed, your fan speed *will* increase. See: [Controlling HP ProLiant DL380 G6/G7 fan speed](https://serverfault.com/questions/312021/controlling-hp-proliant-dl380-g6-g7-fan-speed)

---

*The image below is from a Gen8 ProLiant, but the hottest areas of the server are basically the same as a G6 or G7. CPU zone and the onboard RAID and PCIe sockets.*
[image]

The DL380 G6 has 30 temperature sensors. This is from a healthy running G6. Your temperature reading at sensor 30 is not abnormal:

```
# hplog -t
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS    CURRENT  THRESHOLD 
 1  Basic Sensor Ambient         Normal    71F/ 22C 105F/ 41C 
 2  Basic Sensor CPU (1)         Normal   104F/ 40C 179F/ 82C 
 3  Basic Sensor CPU (2)         Normal   104F/ 40C 179F/ 82C 
 4  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   102F/ 39C 188F/ 87C 
 5  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    96F/ 36C 188F/ 87C 
 6  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    95F/ 35C 188F/ 87C 
 7  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    96F/ 36C 188F/ 87C 
 8  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal   109F/ 43C 194F/ 90C 
 9  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    95F/ 35C 149F/ 65C 
10  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   116F/ 47C 194F/ 90C 
11  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    98F/ 37C 158F/ 70C 
12  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   105F/ 41C 194F/ 90C 
13  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    96F/ 36C 158F/ 70C 
14  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    98F/ 37C 158F/ 70C 
15  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    98F/ 37C 158F/ 70C 
16  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    87F/ 31C 158F/ 70C 
17  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   100F/ 38C 158F/ 70C 
18  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 158F/ 70C 
19  Basic Sensor Processor Zone  Normal    84F/ 29C 158F/ 70C 
20  Basic Sensor Processor Zone  Normal    87F/ 31C 158F/ 70C 
21  Basic Sensor Processor Zone  Normal    93F/ 34C 176F/ 80C 
22  Basic Sensor Processor Zone  Normal    91F/ 33C 176F/ 80C 
23  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   102F/ 39C 170F/ 77C 
24  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    91F/ 33C 158F/ 70C 
25  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    89F/ 32C 158F/ 70C 
26  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    89F/ 32C 158F/ 70C 
27  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 158F/ 70C 
28  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   102F/ 39C 158F/ 70C 
29  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    95F/ 35C 140F/ 60C 
30  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   156F/ 69C 230F/110C
```

The fans for the same system are:

```
# hplog -f
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS  REDUNDANT FAN SPEED 
 1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Low    ( 13)
 2  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Low    ( 34)
 3  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Medium ( 41)
 4  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Medium ( 43)
 5  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Medium ( 43)
 6  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Low    ( 37)
```

Answer (score 0):

If sensor 29 is reporting high temps when otherwise the server appears to be running idle, it could be that you have non-HP branded drives that are not correctly reporting SMART stats, causing the server to mistakenly think the drives are overheating and so it ramps up the fans. Check out this article for more info: http://dascomputerconsultants.com/HPCompaqServerDrives.htm