# HP DL380G6: Where is the Temp. Sensor #29 (System Zone)?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, physical-environment, fan

The Temp. Sensor #29 of my HP DL380G6 seems to give me a wrong number. It says that the temperature is more than 50C (Caution: 60C, Critical: 65C) while the actual value is 13C. And I think it may be the reason why all fans run madly at 78% of the full speed and make an extremely loud noise. Please  tell me where the sensor is and how to solve this problem.
The iLO is the latest version (v2.23) as well as the BIOS (2013.07.02).
Thanks a lot.

> Temp 1:     Ambient Zone     Ok     13C     Caution: 41C; Critical:45C
>   Temp 2:     CPU 1     Ok     40C     Caution: 82C; Critical:83C
>   Temp 3:     CPU 2     n/a     n/a     Caution: 82C; Critical:83C
>   Temp 4:     Memory Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 87C; Critical:92C
>   Temp 5:     Memory Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 87C; Critical:92C
>   Temp 6:     Memory Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 87C; Critical:92C
>   Temp 7:     Memory Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 87C; Critical:92C
>   Temp 8:     Power Supply Zone     Ok     19C     Caution: 90C; Critical:95C
>   Temp 9:     Power Supply Zone     Ok     16C     Caution: 65C; Critical:70C
>   Temp 10:     I/O Board Zone     Ok     19C     Caution: 90C; Critical:95C
>   Temp 11:     I/O Board Zone     Ok     15C     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 12:     I/O Board Zone     Ok     20C     Caution: 90C; Critical:95C
>   Temp 13:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 14:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 15:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 16:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 17:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 18:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 19:     CPU Zone     Ok     14C     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 20:     CPU Zone     Ok     16C     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 21:     CPU Zone     Ok     20C     Caution: 80C; Critical:85C
>   Temp 22:     CPU Zone     Ok     16C     Caution: 80C; Critical:85C
>   Temp 23:     I/O Board Zone     Ok     18C     Caution: 77C; Critical:82C
>   Temp 24:     Memory Zone     Ok     15C     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 25:     Memory Zone     Ok     14C     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 26:     Memory Zone     Ok     15C     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 27:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 28:     I/O Board Zone     n/a     n/a     Caution: 70C; Critical:75C
>   Temp 29:     System Zone     Ok     51C     Caution: 60C; Critical:65C
>   Temp 30:     I/O Board Zone     Ok     38C     Caution: 110C; Critical:115C

Answer (score 3):

Please see: [HP DL380 G6: Where is Temperature Sensor 30 (I/O Board Zone)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/514330/hp-dl380-g6-where-is-temperature-sensor-30-i-o-board-zone/514333#514333)

I happen to be sitting in front of a DL380 G6 with a bad temperature sensor right now. I've seen these sensors got bad and require a system board replacement. So it's a bit of a warranty issue.

In addition, the riser cards on these servers tend to have problems...

In your case, though, do you have any PCIe cards installed in the system? Depending on which cards are installed, the [system fans will behave accordingly](https://serverfault.com/questions/312021/controlling-hp-proliant-dl380-g6-g7-fan-speed).

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue.  I am relatively certain that sensor 29 indicates the heat on the northbridge chip which is immediately behind the processors.

Comment: This would still indicate a fault, no? Did the problem develop suddenly?

Comment: This is what happens on my system.  sensor 29 starts at 43.  It will slowly climb to 47c.  When this happens the fans will ramp up to cool the system.  At this point 1 or 2 things will occur: 1) The temp will fall below 46c which will allow the fans to ramp down -OR- 2) the temp will hover at 46c which will not allow the fans to ramp down.

The mobo wants to keep the temp of that sensor below 115 and will ramp the fans to accomplish this.

It did not happen suddenly to me, its just the way my server has been.  In regards to the original poster, try replacing the thermal paste on the NB.

Answer (score 0):

Sensor 29 on HP DL380 servers reports temps on your HDDs, and for certain brands/models of drive they don't report a value that the server can correctly interpret, causing the server to think it's overheating, which causes the fans to slowly ramp up to max. Check this article for more info: http://dascomputerconsultants.com/HPCompaqServerDrives.htm