# HP Proliant DL360 G6 Sensor #27 Storage Zone

Tags: hp

I have two HP Proliant DL360 G6 Servers where ilo shows me high temperatures for Sensor 27 (Storage Zone). The Values are 59-63 Degrees. 
All other sensorvalues are clearly lower.
Does anybody knows where the Sensor 27 is located?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using non-HP disks in the server?

Comment: Yes, I use Hitachi Disk. I know that non-HP disks have problems with the "overheating" message. Is the overheating message the same as sensor 27?

Comment: What specific disk models are you using? Are they SATA or consumer disks?

Comment: SATA consumer disks 24/7 . HTE721010A9E630

Answer (score 3):

Your server is overheating because you're using non-HP drives who aren't reporting temperature correctly to the system and backplane. The Hitachi model you mentioned (HTE721010A9E630) is a *laptop* computer hard drive. Don't do this!

The location of the sensor doesn't really matter as much as the use of incompatible equipment.

However, your ILO interface will show you where each temperature sensor is.

Please see: [HP DL380 G6: Where is Temperature Sensor 30 (I/O Board Zone)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/514330/hp-dl380-g6-where-is-temperature-sensor-30-i-o-board-zone/514333#514333)