# HP DL380 G7 fans speed up when i plug GPU

Tags: hp-proliant

i have a hp proliant dl380 g7 server.

when i plug to pci-e a GPU (Gigabyte gt 610) and power on the server, the fans speed up a lot to make too much noise.
when i unplug the GPU and power on the server, fans (and noise ofc) goes back to normal-quiet.

what should i do to have the GPU plugged-in and the fans go to their normal RPM ?

Thanks

Comment: The additional heat generated by the GPU has to go somewhere. According to the specs the card draws 300W power. Do you really expect that has no impact?

Comment: It's a normal behavior in my opinion. server room are closed for that reason :) (unless it's a lab you do and it's in your closet)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider ofc i was sure that the fans will speed up, but they speed up from like 10-20% up to 80% in a cold room (5 degrees in room, 20-40 degrees cpu temperature on 100%).

got it on a small room next to my bedroom, and it is kinda annoying

there is no way to reduce the rpm ? thanks

Comment: @mox21r its great sound to get asleep

Comment: `got it on a small room next to my bedroom, and it is kinda annoying` - Servers are meant to be in server rooms, not spare bedrooms. If the noise is too much for you then move it to another room where you can't hear it or remove the GPU.

Comment: First line of our help pages says "Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment" - this doesn't count. Also if you absolutely must do this don't do it with an obsolete GPU, even a cheapo 1050 will outperform a 610 by quite a margin, use a lot less power and generate a lot less heat - plus you don't need to run any extra power lines to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't control this. The server fans increase RPM because of the type of card you've inserted. This is especially true for cards that require greater cooling or draw more power.

Please see: [Controlling HP ProLiant DL380 G6/G7 fan speed](https://serverfault.com/questions/312021/controlling-hp-proliant-dl380-g6-g7-fan-speed)

Comment: thats sad. is there any way that i can at least control the fans ? (like a program or something). if not, is it safe to unistall 2 out of 6 fans ? (since it is in a really cold room, and the cpu's temprature is around 20-40 Celsius degrees)

Comment: @mox21r the fans are there for a reason, do not uninstall them if you do not want to risk damaging you server