# Manually control fans on an HP Proliant server

Tags: linux, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, fan

I have an HP ProLiant DL380 Gen 5 server. I want to adjust the "fan curve" to allow the fans to be switched off while the CPU and the RAM are cool enough.

Is this even possible, and if so how would I go about it? I have searched [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/312021/controlling-hp-proliant-dl380-g6-g7-fan-speed) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/312021/controlling-hp-proliant-dl380-g6-g7-fan-speed) with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For the curious: The reasons I have an old, outdated server as a home server are as follows:

1) they are cheap off of ebay (I have very little budget)

2) I need a fair amount of RAM (mine has 64GiB) and processing power (for game servers etc.)

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? Why don't you let the fans run the way they were designed to run?

Comment: @joeqwerty because I want to reduce the noise wherever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be possible through normal means.

The ILO and system management utilities control the fan performance, so ensure the HP drivers and health agents are installed. If you require something quiet, the tower models of the same generation are close to silent. This server may not be ideal for your use case.